# How can I output the coordinates of a city in coordinates of the Mercator projection?

Tags: curated-data, coordinate-transformation, geography

On *Mathematica* version 8, I would like to use `CountryData` and `CityData` to mark Paris on a polygon map of France in the Mercator projection.  In the example below, you will see that I'm able to mark Paris on a default/equirectangular projection map of France, but not on a Mercator projection.

First, I'll use `CountryData` to obtain coordinate data for France:

```
franceCoords1 = CountryData["France", "Polygon"][[1]];
franceCoords2 = CountryData["France", {"Polygon", "Equirectangular"}][[1]];
franceCoords3 = Map[Reverse, CountryData["France", "Coordinates"], {2}];
franceCoords4 = CountryData["France", {"Polygon", "Mercator"}][[1]];
```

The first three lists are actually identical:

```
(franceCoords1 == franceCoords2) && (franceCoords2 == franceCoords3)
franceCoords1 == franceCoords4
```

> True
>
> False

The first three are the default/equirectangular projection, while `franceCoords4` is the Mercator projection.

I can plot all these coordinates by using `Graphics` wrapped around `Polygon` objects:

```
Grid[{
  Map[
   Graphics[Polygon[#], Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 200] &
   , {franceCoords1, franceCoords2, franceCoords3, franceCoords4}]
  }]
```

[image: maps1]

It's pretty clear that the first three are the same (default/equirectangular) projection, whereas `franceCoords4` is a different (i.e., Mercator) projection.

Now, I can obtain the coordinates of Paris by using `CityData`:

```
parisCoords = Reverse[CityData[{"Paris", "France"}, "Coordinates"]]
```

> {2.34, 48.86}

(`CityData` gives coordinates as **{latitude, longitude}** ordered pairs, whereas a "conventional" world map is **{x, y} = {longitude, latitude}**, so in `parisCoords` I have reversed the coordinates given by `CityData`.)

I can mark Paris on the maps by using `Point[parisCoords]`:

```
Grid[{
  Map[
   Graphics[{
      Polygon[#],
      Red, PointSize[Large], Point[parisCoords]
      }, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 200] &
   , {franceCoords1, franceCoords2, franceCoords3, franceCoords4}]
  }]
```

[image: mapswithcity]

It looks like the location of Paris is correct in `franceCoords1`, `franceCoords2`, and `franceCoords3` ... but not in `franceCoords4`.  This is because the maps given by `franceCoords1`, `franceCoords2`, and `franceCoords3` are given in default/equirectangular coordinates, whereas the map given by `franceCoords4` is given by Mercator projection coordinates.

So, my question is, ***how can I convert the default/equirectangular coordinates of Paris to coordinates in the Mercator projection?***

Probably doing so would be simpler in *Mathematica* version 10, which I understand introduced new geography features, but I don't have access to version 10.  I would like to accomplish it in version 8, please.

Is there any built-in way for `CityData` to output the coordinates of Paris in the Mercator projection, or to convert the default/equirectangular coordinates to coordinates in the Mercator projection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I had to tidy this answer up:

Functional way to **change coordinates in Mathematica** is to use combination of `GeoPosition` and `GeoGridPosition`:

```
GeoGridPosition[GeoPosition[{lat, long}], (*projection*) ]
```

---

The answer should be done here but there is some unconsistency for older than **V10** versions.

**There is different scalling applied to directly downloaded data and different when you manually convert from equirectangular coordinates**:

```
    (*direct download world in mercator projection*)
worldMercV9 = CountryData["World", {"SchematicPolygon", "Mercator"}];

    (*manual conversion*)
worldV9 = CountryData["World", "SchematicPolygon"];
worldFromEqToMercV9 = Map[
   First @ GeoGridPosition[GeoPosition[Reverse[#]], "Mercator"] &, 
   worldV9, 
   {3}]



Graphics[#, Frame -> True] & /@ {worldMercV9, worldFromEqToMercV9} // Row
```

[image]

so yeah, good luck.

- You can't directly download Paris coordinates in mercator projection so you have to take care about rescalling by yourself.
- Or you can go other way. Download everything in equirectangular projection and then proceed with changing coordinates, as [kguler](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/72963/5478) has demonstrated.

---

```
franceMERC = CountryData["France", {"Polygon", "Mercator"}];

parisEq = CityData["Paris", "Coordinates"] (* => {48.86, 2.34}*)

parisMerc = Composition[
             Rescale[# - {Pi, 0}, {-Pi, Pi}, {-180., 180}] &,
             First,
             GeoGridPosition[#, "Mercator"] &,
             GeoPosition
            ][parisEq]    (* => {2.34, 56.1549}*)

Graphics[{
  franceMERC,
  AbsolutePointSize@12, Red, Point@parisMerc
  },
  Frame -> True]
```

[image]

---

**Fortunately, in V10 it is consistent.**

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps

```
mpF = GeoGridPosition[GeoPosition[#], "Mercator"][[1]] &;

g1 = Graphics[{Gray, CountryData["France", "Polygon"], 
               PointSize[Large], Red, Point[parisCoords]}, ImageSize -> 300];
g2 = Graphics[{Gray, Polygon[mpF /@ CountryData["France", "Coordinates"]], Red, 
               PointSize[Large], Point@mpF[Reverse@parisCoords]}, ImageSize -> 300];

Row[{g1, g2}]
```

[image]